# CLLocationManager swift does´t work

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

Im trying to do a simple app. Just a map with the users location. I search in here the solution, but I think that I have everything and still does´t work.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var MapView: MKMapView = nil
    var location : CLLocationManager! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        location = CLLocationManager()
        location.delegate = self
        location.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        location.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I added `NSLoscationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in `info.plist`. I activated `Debug -> Location -> Custom Location` in the iOS simulator.

I am not sure if I have to put something in `AppDelegate.swift` (It's my first app).

I will be very grateful if you can help me!!

Thanks. :)

Comment: Can you please explain _exactly_ what you mean by "still doesn't work"?  What happens or doesn't happen that you expected?  What error(s) are you getting?  If you added NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key in the info.plist, you should also call `location.requestAlwaysAuthorization()`.

Comment: Also note `NSLoscationWhenInUseUsageDescription` is misspelled.  It should be `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

Comment: Thank you so much Anna for your help, now it show the users location, I think that it was the mistake in "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription". But I think that the app has to ask for permission but does´t show anything about that. I'm not getting any error.